# Find all positive integer solutions to the equation $(2x-1)^3 + 16 = y^4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to approach this kind of questions ?

I just knew that y is odd and wrote the equation as $(2x-1)^3 = (y^2 + 4)$(y+2)(y-2)
I don't know what to do after this . Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: To start have a look at $n=16$ in the table here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Generalization So you want to try that no solutions exist ...

Comment: factors are pairwise coprime, so each must be a cube

Comment: Thanks @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: Thanks @WillJagy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such solutions.

HINT: First note that $y$ must be odd. For odd $y$ though, note that $y^2+4$ and $y^2-4$ are relatively prime so each must be a cube. They differ by only 8 though. So $y^2+4$ cannot be any larger than 27. That narrows down possibilities you need to check considerably.

Comment: Thanks @Mike but how did you get that $y^2 + 4$ cannot be larger than 27

Comment: @AdhirajSinghBrar Consecutive cubes larger than $27$ have differences greater than $8$, for example $4^3 - 3^3 = 39 > 8$.

Comment: Thanks @SeokbinLee